# Copy data from one table and Clear and update new data into another table in another sheet in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro which is currently copying data from Setup sheet and updating into the respective tables into Read_Only sheet for the first time. But when I click second time, it is adding the data into the respective tables in Read_Only sheet.

Now what I want is, if I click second time, it should first clear the existing data from that respective table in Read_Only sheet and then update the new data into that table. (For example: In 1st table, there were 10 rows of data, now when I click 2nd time I have only 8 rows of data, then macro should clear data existing 10 rows of data and update this new 8 rows of data and then delete the 2 empty two rows. This should be Dynamic, since number of rows may vary every time while updating new data)

Here is the existing code:

```
Sub copyData()

    Dim wsSet As Worksheet
    Dim wsRead As Worksheet
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wRow As Integer
    Dim strCat As String
    Dim catRow As Integer

    Set wsSet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Budget_Setup")
    Set wsRead = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WBS_Overview_Read_only")
    Set rngSearch = wsRead.Range("A12:A1000")    'range in READ to search for category
    lastRow = wsSet.Range("B16").End(xlDown).Row     'last row of data in SET

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 17 To lastRow
        strCat = Left(wsSet.Range("b" & i).Value, 3)    'current category in SET
        catRow = rngSearch.Find(strCat).Row             'row of match in READ
        If wsRead.Range("a" & catRow + 1).Value = "" Then   'find the correct row to copy into
            wRow = catRow + 1
        Else
            wRow = wsRead.Range("a" & catRow).End(xlDown).Row + 1
            If wsRead.Range("e" & wRow).Value <> "" Then
                wsRead.Range("a" & wRow).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        End If
        wsSet.Range("b" & i & ":f" & i).Copy
        wsRead.Range("a" & wRow).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set wsRead = Nothing
    Set wsSet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can someone please help me?  It is bit urgent.  Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: Would it work for you if you just cleared the read only sheet before repopulating the data from the setup sheet?

Comment: Yes, it should clear at a phase level.  For example if I am trying to update phase .71, then macro should clear only phase .71 data and update new data and if there are any blank rows in that phase, then .  If I am trying to update two phases .72 and .75 at a time, then it should first clear data only in these two phases and then update new data.  If I am trying to update all phases, then it should clear all phases data and then update new data in all phases.

Comment: just wanted to know how to attach a sample file or screen shot here?

Comment: Don't think you can given your rep level

Comment: Hi Jaycal,  Sorry, I didn't get you what you're saying.

Comment: Your reputation level (currently 1 as you're new to the site) may not permit you to post screenshots with your question. As you ask/answer more questions, you'll be able to do so. For now, maybe you can post a sample file to a dropbox-type filesharing site?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I have just added the sample file in the Dropbox website.  Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m4uue4ddizxisf/Book1.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you.  I added one line to your code:

```
For i = 17 To lastRow
    strCat = Left(wsSet.Range("b" & i).Value, 3)    'current category in SET
    catRow = rngSearch.Find(strCat).Row             'row of match in READ
    If wsRead.Range("a" & catRow + 1).Value = "" Then   'find the correct row to copy into
        wRow = catRow + 1

        wsRead.Rows(wRow).EntireRow.Insert 'I added this line

    Else
        wRow = wsRead.Range("a" & catRow).End(xlDown).Row + 1 'end of data
        If wsRead.Range("e" & wRow).Value <> "" Then
```

Now, run this code before running yours.

```
Sub deletePhases()
'   delete phases in Setup from ReadOnly
    Dim r As Range, Col As Collection
    Dim x As Long, l As Long

    With Budget_Setup
        Set r = .Range("b17", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With
    If r.Row < 17 Then Exit Sub 'no data

    Set Col = New Collection 'build unique list
    On Error Resume Next
    For x = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        Col.Add Left(r(x).Value, 3), Left(r(x).Value, 3)
    Next x

    With ReadOnly
        For x = 1 To Col.Count
            l = .Columns(1).Find(Col(x)).Offset(1).Row '1 below heading
                Do Until .Cells(l, 1) = "" 'end of phase data
                    .Rows(l).Delete
                Loop
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Splendid work Dave.  It is working as expected.  You're the best!!!!!.  Can you please let me know how to rate this?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't be able to vote up this code, since I am having only 1 reputation and it requires 15 reputations to vote up.  Once again thank you so much for your help Dave.  Have a great day!!!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Can you check of this question as answered, thanks?

Comment: Hi Dave,  Could you please help me how can I check of this question as answered?  I looked into the various options and couldn't able to find it.

Comment: Click the blank check mark that's located underneath the up/down voting arrows.

Comment: As per your request, I have just clicked on the tick mark.  Please let me know if I need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This code will first delete all the existing data in each of the sections on the `Read_Only` sheet; then, with one modification, your code can be run as is.

Add this line of code immediately after `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

```
' Erase all data in the Read Only Sheet
    Set currentData = wsRead.Columns(4).Find("Subject")

    Do
        wsRead.Range(currentData.Offset(2, 0), _
            currentData.Offset(2, 0).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
        Set currentData = wsRead.Columns(4).FindNext(currentData)
    Loop Until Not currentData Is Nothing And currentData.Row = 12
```

*This code uses the "Subject" and the "Budgeted Cost" cells to delete the existing data between it.*

Next, add the following line of code immediately after `wRow = catRow + 1`

```
wsRead.Rows(wRow).EntireRow.Insert
```

*this will add the first blank row of data to a given section. Your existing code will then insert the new data into the blank row*

Comment: This code is actually deleting data for all phases, but want I want is, 2nd time If I am updating only for Phase.72, then it should delete data only in a phase.72 and update data from the Setup sheet.

Comment: Also if we have data for all phases in Setup sheet, then it is working perfectly fine, but If I delete few phases data in Setup sheet and try to update only one phase then first time it is replacing the data correctly, but second time it is deleting budgeted cost row in all other phases in ReadOnly sheet.  Is it possible to fix this as well?

Comment: Hi Jaycal,  Could you please help me on this?  I know it's bit complex.  I have been trying to fix this from past two days, but still couldn't able to Figure out a solution.

Comment: Just so I'm clear on this - if you have no data for Phase.72, for example, in the Setup sheet, you want all that data cleared, but you want to keep the Phase.72 headings & Budgeted cost rows, is that correct?

Comment: Well, I tried @Jaycal code, and it worked perfectly for me.  Basically, deletes all data rows from ReadOnly, then updates Readonly with current data from Setup.  Which is what you wanted ,right?

Comment: No.  It should delete data only at a Phase level not all phases.  As I said earlier, If I am updating data only for phase.71 in Setup sheet (you can just try deleting other phases .72 to .75 in the Setup sheet) and if you try to update even now it is deleting all phases in ReadOnly sheet. Here I want macro to delete only Phase .71    and not all phases. If I am updating Phase .72, then it should delete only .72 data in ReadOnly sheet.  Are you following me?  If I am updating .71 & .74 phases in Setup sheet, then it should delete .72 and .74 phases in Readonly sheet and update from Setup sheet.

Comment: To understand even better, I am giving this following example.  Assume that Setup sheet has only .71 data and ReadOnly sheet has all 5 phases (i.e. .71, .72, .73, .74 & .75 phases) data records.  Now if I presss Update data button in Setup sheet, it should delete data rows only in .71 phase of ReadOnly sheet and update new .71 data from the Setup sheet. Is it more clear?

Comment: Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: Yes, now that gives us a better understanding of what you're trying to do.  Need some time to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're defining your Phase.71, Phase.72, etc, ranges, but with the information we have, this might work for you.

```
Sub clearAll()
Dim r As Range, vArr, v
vArr = Array("Phase.71", "Phase.72", "Phase.73", "Phase.74", "Phase.75")
For Each v In vArr
    Set r = ReadOnly.Range(v)
    Set r = r.Offset(2).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 4)
    r.ClearContents
Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting an error message stating "Run-time error" '424' Object required" when code comes to row "Set r = ReadOnly.Range(v).  Also this is not Dynamic, since data in phases is not always 5 rows, some will have 20 rows and some will have only 4 rows.  How to clear contents dynamically and also delete the remaining rows dynamically

Comment: I don't understand why you're getting that error code, it works OK for me, on your workbook.  As far as not being dynamic, I realize the code as such isn't dynamic, but surely your range names (Phase.71, Phase.72, etc) must be dynamic  - they're what's being referenced in the macro.

Comment: Is it possible for you to do the changes in Jaycal's code as per my requirement?  I am very much worried because I am thinking that I may not be able to achieve what I wanted.  Any help highly appreciated.